# plain text display with vert. scrolling?

Tags: android

Is there an example that would allow a few hundred or thousand words, with paragraphs and CRs, to be displayed in a basic Hello World-style text display, complete with a vert. scroll bar (or vertical grab and move up or down)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `WebView`. Convert your carriage returns into `<br>` tags via `replaceAll()` on `String`.

Or, use a `TextView` inside of a `ScrollView`.